# Deciding whether a context-free language is regular

Tags: regular-language, context-free, decidability

Does anyone know whether the following decision problem is decidable:

Given a context-free language $L$, is $L$ regular?

Here $L$ can be expressed, e.g., using a context-free grammar. Does anyone know an algorithm that takes as input a context-free grammar $G$ and outputs an equivalent regular grammar $G'$, i.e. $L(G) = L(G')$, if $L(G)$ is regular?

Comment: You could either use [Greibach Theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach%27s_theorem) to show it's undecidable, or just notice that universality is undecidable for CFGs, but is decidable for regular languages.

Comment: Not a research level question.

Comment: I think this is a pretty interesting (research level) question.  Thanks for asking.  :)

Comment: @RB Indeed, undecidability follows directly from [Greibach's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greibach%27s_theorem). Thanks!

Comment: @RB I agree about Greibach's theorem, but I believe the two facts about universality are not enough. They can be used to show that it's not possible to *convert* a CFG to a regular language when possible, but this does not yet mean it's undecidable to merely *decide* whether a context-free language is regular.

Answer (score 10):

Regularity is decidable for DCFL, but it is undecidable for general Context-Free Languages.

Regarding DCFL, I have two references (from Hopcroft+Ullman 79):

- [A regularity test for pushdown machines](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995867905918),  R.E. Stearns, Information and Control, 1967 (full text by clicking on the page)
- [Regularity and Related Problems for Deterministic Pushdown Automata](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.129.8903&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Leslie G. Valiant, JACM 1975

Regarding a procedure to get a regular version when possible, I have no suggestion.

Comment: The procedure to get a regular grammar can't exist. Given a Turing machine $M$ one can construct a Context-free grammar whose language is either $\Sigma^{*}$ or $\Sigma^{*} - w$ depending on whether $M$ halts. These are both regular languages and so if we could exhibit a regular grammar we could decide the halting problem. The full proof is in Shallit's book http://www.amazon.co.uk/Second-Course-Formal-Languages-Automata/dp/0521865727

Comment: @SamJones Is that still true for deterministic CFLs?